# How to preload images using Volley

Tags: android, image, listview, android-volley, image-loading

I am new to android. I am using android volley library to load images and post request. I am loading five items in a list view for the first time. And after the scrolling the fifth item , now i am loading the next five items in the list view. My question is images are been loading  only when its view is appeared on the display screen. How Can i pre-load the images once i add items to list view and when i scroll the list view, i need to view the loaded image. Thanks to one and all .

```
if ((loadedItems == totalItemCount) && totalItemCount != 0) {

    if (max < productscount) {
    min = max;
    max = max + 5;

    if (min == 0) {             
        lastpost_id = "";
    }               

    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        alert.showAlertDialog(
        ActivityPreloved.this,          
        "Internet Connection Error",
        "Please connect to working Internet connection",
        false);
        return;
    } else {
        activityScreenVolleyExecute();
        app_session.setScrollVal("1");                      
    }                   
}
```

Comment: you can add footer view and put progressBar inside it and when all your images downloaded remove that. volley has a built in listener for download completion.

Comment: "My question is images are been loading only when its view is appeared on the display screen." - That's how the ListView's Adapter works. For efficiency's sake, it will not load the data at a particular position until it's 'about to be' displayed on the screen. If you want to pre-load all the images, you'll have to do that before adding it to your ListView's Adapter; not when the View is being loaded during a getView() call.